# Difference between &++x and &x++

Tags: c++, post-increment, pre-increment, unary-operator, postfix-operator

Although this question might be answered somewhere and I could not find it.

Below written first statement work whereas second does not? WHY?

```
int main() {
  int x = 1, y = 2;

  int *p = &++x; // First
  std::cout << "*p = " << *p << std::endl;

  // int *q = &x++; // Second
  // std::cout << "*q = " << *p << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `&x++` will not even compile. In layman terms, it returns a temporary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this declaration

```
int *p = &++x;
```

there are used two unary operators: pre-increment ++ and taking of address. Unary operators are executed from right to left. So at first the variable `x` is incremented and its address is assigned to the pointer p, The result of the pre-increment operator is `lvalue` of the incremented object.

So for example such an expression like this

```
++++x;
```

is correct.

In this declaration

```
int *p = &x++;
```

there are used the postfix operator post-increment ++ and the unary operator of taking address. Postfix operators have a higher priority relative to unary operators. SO at first the post-increment is executed. Its result is a temporary object that has the value of the variable x before incrementing. Then the operator of taking of address is executed.

However you may not take an address of a temporary object. So for this declaration the compiler will issue an error.

Opposite to the pre-increment operator such an expression like this

```
x++++;
```

is invalid.

From the C++ 17 Standard (5.3.2 Increment and decrement)

> 1 The operand of prefix ++ is modified by adding 1, or set to true if
>   it is bool (this use is deprecated). The operand shall be a modifiable
>   lvalue. The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type or a
>   pointer to a completely-defined object type. **The result is the
>   updated operand; it is an lvalue**, and it is a bit-field if the
>   operand is a bit-field....

And (5.2.6 Increment and decrement)

> 1 **The value of a postfix ++ expression is the value** of its operand. [
>   Note: the value obtained is a copy of the original value — end note
>   ]...

In C the both operations yield a value. So in C you also may not write

```
++++x;
```